# Inconsistant behavior of ndarray in case of blank in python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn

When i am predicting a class using scikit-learn classifier model

```
class=modelftr.predict(X_t)
```

the class variable returns

```
>>class

array(['class1'],dtype='<U47')
```

whereas when I have defined a variable as

`x=np.ndarray([],dtype='<U47')`

calling `x[0]` returns

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array

When i am defining a variable as:

```
class=np.ndarray([''],dtype='<U47')
```

error generates as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> TypeError: an integer is required

Why such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is a 1 element array:

```
In [50]: a=np.array(['one'],dtype='U10')

In [51]: a.shape
Out[51]: (1,)

In [52]: a[0]
Out[52]: 'one'
```

The second is an array with 0 elements.

```
In [53]: a=np.array([],dtype='U10')

In [54]: a.shape
Out[54]: (0,)
```

The only indexing allowed is with an empty tuple:

```
In [56]: a[()]
Out[56]: 
array([], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

On a new numpy, `a[0]` produces `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

As for the last, creation and simple indexing works just as with the first.

```
In [58]: a=np.array([''],dtype='U10')

In [59]: a
Out[59]: 
array([''], 
      dtype='<U10')

In [60]: a[0]
Out[60]: ''
```

what code, exactly, is producing that last error?

Comment: The last error is produced while declaration itself, I am not sure but I feel dtype is responsible.